# How to set a value for a Column in oracle based on query results?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table named `Person` in my `Oracle DB` with the following columns:

```
- ID
- Name
- hasPaid
- sendProduct
```

I want to modify the current value of the `sendProduct` column to be `'Yes'` for any row that has a `hasPaid` value of `'yes'`

```
select * from Person where hasPaid = 'Yes';
```

I have wrote the following query above to get all rows with a hasPaid value of 'Yes' , however I am unsure how to set the hasPaid column using this?

Comment: Do you need to update the table or simply get that value in a select statement, without modifying the data?

Comment: No I want to modify the existing data in the table, thanks

Comment: This is really not the level of question you should be asking on stackoverflow - get a SQL manual and read it. (and no I didn't downvote you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of `OldProgrammer` is correct. 
 
But if you only want to update the rows that need updating, you could also use:

```
UPDATE Person 
SET sendProduct = 'Yes' 
WHERE sendProduct != 'Yes' 
AND hasPaid = 'Yes';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Person
SET sendProduct = 'Yes'
where hasPaid = 'Yes';
```

Maybe read an [SQL Tutorial?](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)  This is a  pretty fundamental DML (Data Manipulation Language) concept.

Comment: the only and ultimative answer